# IBM Domino 502 Bad Gateway on redirect

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, bad-gateway

In our application we have a REST integration with another service

It worked fine untill recently, however, sometimes we are returned with `502 Bad Gateway` in the application

We send HTTP requests through curl and it seems that to be working but then we are presented with the error I described above

The client is believed to have a firewall installed

Whenever we face the problem, I usually ask the administrator to turn this thing off and it does the trick but I'm not sure whether it has something to do with the code?

My question is what causes such behaviour and how to avoid it in the future?

Comment: Not enough info. Application with REST?Is Notes the client? If so, where does curl come in? Is Domino the server your application is communicating with? Are there redirects on the server? Is a reverse proxy involved on the server side?